# Can I speed up my reading and processing of many .csv files in python?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, csv, pyspark

I am currently occupied with a dataset consisting of 90 `.csv` files. There are three types of `.csv` files (30 of each type).

Each csv has from 20k to 30k rows average and 3 columns(timestamp in linux format, Integer,Integer).

Here's an example of the header and a row:

```
Timestamp   id1    id2
151341342   324    112
```

I am currently using 'os' to list all files in the directory.

The process for each CSV file is as follows:

1. Read it through pandas into a dataframe
2. iterate the rows of the file and for each row convert the timestamp to readable format.
3. Use the converted timestamp and Integers to create a relationship-type of object and add it on a list of relationships

The list will later be looped to create the relationships in my neo4j database.
The problem I am having is that the process takes too much time. I have asked and searched for ways to do it faster (I got answers like PySpark, Threads) but I did not find something that really fits my needs. I am really stuck as with my resources it takes around 1 hour and 20 minutes to do all that process for one of the big `.csv` file(meaning one with around 30k rows)
Converting to readable format:

```
ts = int(row['Timestamp'])
formatted_ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

And I pass the parameters to the Relationship func of py2neo to create my relationships. Later that list will be looped .

```
node1 = graph.evaluate('MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.id={id} RETURN n', id=int(row["id1"]))
        node2 = graph.evaluate('MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.id={id} RETURN n', id=int(row['id2']))
        rels.append(Relationship(node1, rel_type, node2, date=date, time=time))
```

```
time to compute row:  0:00:00.001000
time to create relationship:  0:00:00.169622
time to compute row:  0:00:00.001002
time to create relationship:  0:00:00.166384
time to compute row:  0:00:00
time to create relationship:  0:00:00.173672
time to compute row:  0:00:00
time to create relationship:  0:00:00.171142
```

I calculated the time for the two parts of the process as shown above. It is fast and there really seems to not be a problem except the size of the files. This is why the only things that comes to mind is that Parallelism would help to compute those files faster(by computing lets say 4 files in the same time instead of one)

sorry for not posting everything

I am really looking forward for replies

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please include a snippet of your current code in your question?

Comment: Try looking into [dask dataframes](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). You can lazily load all csv's into a single dataframe and operate on them independently.

Comment: Okay, that's better, but still I don't see where your slowdown occurs. As I established below, reading the csv file should be really fast. You show that converting the input to readable format is fast. Converting to relationships takes a bit but nowhere near an hour. Could you specify which part exactly takes so long? Generally we will be able to help you better if you supply all the important information. Put yourself in our shoes: Consider what we know based you your question and what we do not know. Currently you leave a lot open which leaves us fishing in the dark.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am still new to using stackoverflow for personal projects. It really is a lot different than using it just for searching specific things that have been answered maybe even before years.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds fishy to me. Processing csv files of that size should not be that slow.

I just generated a 30k line csv file of the type you described (3 columns filled with random numbers of the size you specified.

```
import random

with open("file.csv", "w") as fid:
    fid.write("Timestamp;id1;id2\n")
    for i in range(30000):
        ts = int(random.random()*1000000000)
        id1 = int(random.random()*1000)
        id2 = int(random.random()*1000)
        fid.write("{};{};{}\n".format(ts, id1, id2))
```

Just reading the csv file into a list using plain Python takes well under a second. Printing all the data takes about 3 seconds.

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_date(string):
    ts = int(string) 
    formatted_ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    split_ts = formatted_ts.split() 
    date = split_ts[0] 
    time = split_ts[1]
    return date

with open("file.csv", "r") as fid:
    header = fid.readline()
    lines = []
    for line in fid.readlines():
        line_split = line.strip().split(";")
        line_split[0] = convert_date(line_split[0])
        lines.append(line_split)

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Could you elaborate what you do after reading the data? Especially "create a relationship-type of object and add it on a list of relationships"

That could help pinpoint your timing issue. Maybe there is a bug somewhere?
You could try timing different parts of your code to see which one takes the longest.

Generally, what you describe should be possible within seconds, not hours.